# How do I add --whole-archive linker option in scons?

Tags: c++, linker, scons

I have a library that only interacts in static scope with an application.  This requires me to link the library with the `--whole-archive` option to avoid the linker from "optimizing" out the library (this is done because the linker never actually sees my library being used).

The issue is that I haven't found a way to add this linker option for a specific library in scons.

```
env.Append(LIBS=['mylib']) #I don't have the linker option
env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-Wl,--whole-archive','-lmylib']) #I don't add myself to the scons dependency tree, I also get added to the link line before the LIBPATH variable.
```

How do I support linker flags elegantly in scons?

Comment: There was a discussion on some [dev list](http://osdir.com/ml/programming.tools.scons.user/2006-05/msg00254.html) in 2006 that google found for me.  That suggests perhaps this issue has been solved, but I still can't find a suitable answer.

Comment: @cape1232 Excuse me but the bounty is ending in 6 minutes and you haven't awarded it to **anyone**.

Comment: @NabeelOmer None of the answers solves the problem.  I'm letting the bounty expire.

Comment: I've been removed from this problem for awhile now, and I never found a good solution.  For reference though this is what made me stop using scons altogether.

Answer (score 2):

## Reworded Question:

**How do I link a static library into a shared library with the --whole-archive link flag, with scons, while maintaining dependencies.**

I am restating your question just to make sure we both have a clear understanding of what you are trying to accomplish.  Please comment if I am not properly capturing the intent of your question.

## Why it is not working for you:

You cannot include the library in `LIBS`, because you want to surround the library with the `--whole-archive` flags.  If you place this entry in the `LINKFLAGS` it could work, but you lose your dependency tracking.

## Answer:

When you move the library from an entry in `LIBS` to an entry in `LINKFLAGS` you lose the *implicit* dependency, but that's fine, just set an *explicit* dependency with `Depends`.

## Working Example:

## File Layout

```
.
├── A.cpp
├── A.h
├── B.cpp
├── B.h
├── main.cpp
└── SConstruct
```

## Files

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int foo2(void) {
    return 2;
}
```

A.h

```
#ifndef __A__
#define __A__
int foo2(void);
#endif
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

int bar(void) {
    return 2 * foo2();
}
```

B.h

```
#ifndef __B__
#define __B__
int bar(void);
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Sum of foo and bar = " << bar() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

SConstruct

```
import os

# Top level Build Environment
env = Environment()

# Library A
envA = env.Clone()
libA = envA.StaticLibrary('A.cpp')

# Library B
envB = env.Clone()
envB.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-Wl,--whole-archive,./libA.a,--no-whole-archive'])
libB = envB.SharedLibrary('B.cpp')
Depends(libB, libA)

# Test Program
envE = env.Clone()
envE.Append(LIBS=['B'],
            LIBPATH=['.'],
            RPATH=[os.path.abspath(os.curdir)])
envE.Program('example', 'main.cpp')
```

## To Run:

Copy all the files to the same directory, and type `scons` in that directory.  This is the output you should see on linux if you build and ask for the dependency tree. (I'm using Fedora 21)

```
>> scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
    engine path: ['/usr/lib/scons/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation

>> scons --tree=prune
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o A.o -c A.cpp
g++ -o B.os -c -fPIC B.cpp
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
ar rc libA.a A.o
ranlib libA.a
g++ -o libB.so -Wl,--whole-archive,./libA.a,--no-whole-archive -shared B.os
g++ -o example -Wl,-rpath=/full/path/to/build/directory main.o -L. -lB
+-.
  +-A.cpp
  +-A.h
  +-A.o
  | +-A.cpp
  | +-A.h
  | +-/bin/g++
  +-B.cpp
  +-B.h
  +-B.os
  | +-B.cpp
  | +-A.h
  | +-B.h
  | +-/bin/g++
  +-SConstruct
  +-example
  | +-main.o
  | | +-main.cpp
  | | +-B.h
  | | +-/bin/g++
  | +-/bin/g++
  | +-libB.so
  |   +-[B.os]
  |   +-libA.a
  |     +-[A.o]
  |     +-/bin/ar
  |     +-/bin/ranlib
  +-[libA.a]
  +-[libB.so]
  +-main.cpp
  +-[main.o]
scons: done building targets.

>> ./example
Sum of foo and bar = 4
```

## What The Example Does:

- Builds a static library A.
- Builds a dynamic library B with the `--whole-archive` link flag on library A.
- Builds an executable that links in library B and executes a function from library B that utilizes a function in library A.
- Properly tracks dependencies between targets.

## Conclusion:

You can see from the dependency graph above that library A is correctly listed as a dependency of library B.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Scons *still* doesn't support link flags such as `-Wl,--whole-archive`.  Using the solution provided by Kenneth E. Bellock is has been working well for many years.  The downside is that this is error prone.  You have to be careful to manage your manual dependency list.

There is an alternate workaround.  Add the following to your SConstruct file:

```
whole_archive = env.Command('-Wl,--whole-archive', [], '')
no_whole_archive = env.Command('-Wl,--no-whole-archive', [], '')
```

Now you can wrap the necessary libraries with whole-archive/no-whole-archive in any combination.  Example:

```
so_libs = env.SharedLibrary('myso', whole_archive+['libfoo1.a']+no_whole_archive+['libbar.a']+whole_archive+['libfoo2.a']+no_whole_archive)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add LIBS and LINKFLAGS to your linker statement.

```
env.SharedLibrary('target',sources,LIBS=['mylib'],LINKFLAGS=env['LINKFLAGS']+['-Wl,--whole-archive','-lmylib'])
```

For example.

Comment: How does that differ fromAlex's second option?  The trouble with adding to LINKFLAGS is that the LINKFLAGS come before LIBS, but you may not want -lmylib to be linked first.  Order matters for linking.

Comment: Order matters for linking static libraries, but not so much for shared libraries ( or at least not in the same way).  What he probably really would like is something like LIBS=[WHOLELIB('mylib'),'otherlib'], but there is no direct support for this in SCons at this time.  It's probably possible to do this by redefining _LIBFLAGS with some more advanced usage of the string substitution logic.

Comment: I have this problem for a static library and something like LIBS=[WHOLELIB(mylib), ...] would be perfect.  Sigh.