# Forcing compile time error for "undefined symbol" in scons

Tags: c, scons

I am having a problem where I get this error: "undefined symbol: someVar" at runtime.  I would like to get that error at link time.

I would like to force a link error similar to this issue:
[Easy check for unresolved symbols in shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617286/easy-check-for-unresolved-symbols-in-shared-libraries)

I am using scons, so I am looking for an scons specific answer.

My scons rule looks like this:

```
def create_objs(SRCS):
    return [env.Object(src) for src in SRCS]

object_mylib = ['mylib.c'
,'one.c'
,'two.c'
]

env.SharedLibrary('#/lib/mylib',    create_objs(object_mylib))
```

I found this issue for adding linker flags in scons:
[How do I add --whole-archive linker option in scons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122498/how-do-i-add-whole-archive-linker-option-in-scons)

A) Is my best option to pattern a solution after those two issues to add the proper flag?

B) Is there a better way?

It seems that some doubt that I am getting this error at runtime, so I am adding this detail:
I get this error:

```
could not load /somepath/libmylib.so for /somepath/libmylib.so: undefined symbol: someVar
```

On this code:

```
char *libFile = "/somepath/libmylib.so";
Handle = dlopen(libFile, RTLD_LAZY);
if (!Handle)
{
    printf("could not load %s for %s", libFile, dlerror());
}
```

during runtime.

My backup plan is to write a small program that does the dlopen and add that to the SConscript.

Comment: Are you sure you get it at *run-time* and not as a linker error? And no, the compiler can't detect that error, only the linker can do it. But since the build process consists of compilation directly followed by linking, I fail to see the problem, as you will (should) get the error when building and not when running the program.

Comment: I added detail to demonstrate that it is happening at runtime.

Comment: If you try to load a library using `dlopen`, how would the compiler (or linker) ever know if it will fail or not?

Comment: I would invoke my small program in SConscript after the .so is linked.  The small program would exit with an exit code that would indicate success or failure.  At that point scons would stop upon failure.  The small program would take an arbitrary .so as an argument.  That is the backup plan.  The better way is to get the linker to report it and fail accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer I (the OP) came up with:
Add

```
env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['-Wl,-z,defs'])
```

to `SConstruct`

Now this command runs:

```
gcc -o lib/libmylib.so -Wl,-z,defs -shared build/mylib.o build/one.o build/two.o
```

Which outputs this error:

```
build/one.o: In function `somefunc':
/home/.../src/one.c:34: undefined reference to `someVar'
```

This works for me.  I will wait while before accepting this answer to see if anyone comes up with a better technique or improvements to this technique.